# Is there a deadman's switch feature in Ubuntu?

Tags: security

Is there a function in Ubuntu or that can be added that would create a deadman's switch?

In effect, I would like to have a feature that, when I'm working on a specific sensitive file, periodically asks me for a password or will close/shut down the file.

Comment: Define "working on" and "shut down the file". What is it you're actually doing?

Comment: ...and maybe tell us the fileformat, as this function will probably be application specific.

Comment: By 'working on' I mean a file open on screen or minimized but available to make changes to the data.  In particular I am thinking of LibreOffice spreadsheets or word documents.